# Select2 optional preselected tags and no result handling

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-select2

**EDIT: I found a temporary workaround for the no result handling. You can return a no results found tag with an id of 0. It's still selectable, but you can skip it when inserting the tags into the database like so:**

```
if($tagId != 0){
    // tag is not the no result tag, so continue
}
```

**It's a temporary solution, and the other question still stands.**

**EDIT 2: The no result handling question is answered. I had a mistake in my code that made turned preSelectedTags into a PHP error. Oops.**

I've been searching for two days now and I can't seem to find the answer(s).

I'm using [select2](https://select2.github.io/) to add a tag-functionality. It shows up fine and it works when there are tags set. However, the whole thing breaks when there are no preselected tags. Here's what my select2 looks like:

```
$('.candidateTags').select2({
    //omitted for brevity
}).select2('data',preSelectedTags);
```

preSelectedTags is a variable that contains json encoded arrays from PHP. This works fine when there tags are actually added, but when it doesn't find anything to preselect, the whole thing crashes.

Also, I can't seem to figure out what the ajax call should return when no results are found. This is what it returns if there are no results:

```
else {
    $results[] = array('id'=> "-1", 'text' => 'Er zijn geen resultaten gevonden');
}

echo json_encode($results);
```

Obviously, this returns a selectable choice, ruining my entire code.
Can someone explain how I can use optional preselects and how I should handle the 'no returns found'-message?

Answer (score 0):

Remove your else condition And Try this Code in your java script,

```
if(typeof(preSelectedTags)=='undefined') {
    $('.candidateTags').select2('data',null);
}
```

Comment: This kind of works. the problem is that now my data set is null. which means that when the user starts typing, Select2 gives the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out my own question(s).

The first part (about the preSelectedTags giving an error and breaking my select2 element):
I used this to create the tags array:

```
var preSelectedTags = [<?php  
    foreach($preSelectedTags as $tag) { 
        echo($tag . ','); 
    }
?>];
```

This works, however when $preSelectedTags is empty, then PHP will turn the preSelectedTags var into an error. To solve this, add an if-statement:

```
if(!empty($preSelectedTags)){
    //code
}
```

Now the second part (about the 'no results found' selectable option):

[There are two ways to solve this, apparently](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/select2/NFJtSdDEQ9U):

The first is to add 'disabled:true' to the json string, so it looks like this:

```
else {
    $results[] = array('id'=> "-1", 'text' => 'no results found', 'disabled' => 'true');
}

echo json_encode($results);
```

However, this did **not** work for me. The other way to solve it did, which was omitting the id in the $results array:

```
else {
    $results[] = array('text' => 'Er zijn geen resultaten gevonden');
}

echo json_encode($results);
```